# C# Parameter not returning new value

Tags: c#, switch-statement, parameter-passing, return-value

I have a method that takes two string parameters and allows the second to be changed if necessary. Utilizing a switch case, I want to change the value of one of the variables passed to a new value ("INVALID.FORMAT@EMAIL.COM").

```
                    string email ="jibberishtext";
                    string url = ...


                    validateData("email", email);
                    if (!email.Contains("INVALID"))
                        sendData(objAcctQryOut, "NET");
```

...

```
    private static string validateData(string mode, string field)
        {    ...
            ElectronicAddressAddUpdateResponse eR = myClient.ElectronicAddressAddUpdate(upd, true, appId, pass);

switch (mode)
            {
                case "email":

                    if (eR.Result.Equals("SUCCESS"))
                        return field;
                    else
                        field = "INVALID.FORMAT@EMAIL.COM";

                    return field;

                case "url":
                 ...
                case "phone":
                 ...

                case "fax":
                 ...

            }
            return field;
        }
```

My question is-- in the validateData method, the second email variable goes back to being populated with the string contained in email "jibberishtext," instead of reflecting the new returned string in variable field. Can someone explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the line:

```
validateData("email", email);
```

to:

```
email = validateData("email", email);
```

You are returning a modified version of the `email` string, so it needs re-assigning to `email`.

If you want to improve upon this, then I'd actually assign the value to a new variable instead, to record the fact that it's now validated:

```
var validatedEmail = validateData("email", email);
```

Finally, your `validateData` method is not a good one. It takes a mode parameter and, depending on the value of that parameter, it performs a series of largely unrelated functions. Rule of thumb: a method should only do one thing. If you have an `if` or `switch` on a parameter, then split your method into individual ones that handle each case.

Answer (score 1):

you could do `string validEmail = validateData("email", email);` Returning a modified email doesn't change the original email.

The values are being passed and copied (pass-by-value).. It is generally not a very good practice to pass primitives (like strings) by reference (using ref keyword) except if they are objects - that is done by default.

Try avoiding static methods and switches if you want a more OOP-like style, and think in terms of objects whenever possible.

Comment: What would be a better alternative to switches in this instance?

Comment: In general you can use polymorphism and objects that implement the validate. Each mode is a different validator class and all them have a validate() method etc.. ;) Also when you enter the testing era you will see that static methods are difficult to mock and test - I don't know if it is overengineered for your example. Switches tend to grow very very - Very long :P

Comment: I can understand that but there's only 4 cases. A bit too long for "if/else," but seems like the perfect scenario for switch. If I had 6+ scenarios, yes, objects that implement the validate seem like the way to go.

Comment: I have worked on projects that had 3-4 cases and now have 20 with switches that became 600 lines long :). Switches are putting the foundations for poor code most often. When I say switches I mean if/elses too! You are also breaking the Single Responsibility Principle of methods/classes etc (read more in books like Clean Code)